# Looking for a formal equivalent phrase for the adverb "personally"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Which one is correct: "personal basis" or "individual basis"? I want to use it in a formal letter. I want to say: "I don't know Mr. X on a personal basis (or individual basis) and I have not had an opportunity to work with him". I want to avoid saying "I don't know Mr. X on personally". In fact, I am looking for an equivalent phrase for the adverb "personally".

Could someone help me?

Comment: You could always say "I have not met him", if that is the case.

Comment: I think the 'Mr X' gives the game away anyway.

Comment: X will be replaced by the real name.

Comment: Only when he's learnt to write.

Answer (score 3):

You can say *I don't know Mr. X personally...* and there's nothing informal about it: it's just a statement of fact. You might want to explain a bit more about how you do know him, though: *...but I'm familiar with his work...*

Comment: +1, while "on a personal basis" is correct, "personally" is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You might say 'I don't know Mr. X in a personal context...'

Answer (score 0):

"I'm not familiar with Mr. X" would be another option.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know him myself* gives the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate to use *personally* here. You might also wish to consider *acquainted*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a recommendation, you will want to avoid saying that all together, and let them read between the lines. Say

> While my exposure to Mr. X's work has been limited to...